# findInterval function in R (set results)

Tags: r

How can I replace the results of the findinterval function with my desired numbers? Below is the dput() output:

```
a=c(113,113,113,113,111,111,115,116,117,118,220,220)
b=c(113,113,113,113,111,111,115,116,117,118,220,220)
c=c(2,2,1,1,5,1,1,2,1,1,1,4)
d=c(2,2,12,12,15,12,12,2,12,12,12,14)
e=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3)
f=c(20,30,25,35,45,55,60,65,70,75,75,80)
h=c("1A","1A","2A","3A","1A","5A","4A","4A","7A","7A","9A","9A")
i=c(12,16,17,19,20,15,18,17,17,13,14,15)

m=data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d,e=e,f=f,h=h,i=i)

dput(m)
structure(list(a = c(113, 113, 113, 113, 111, 111, 115, 116, 
117, 118, 220, 220), b = c(113, 113, 113, 113, 111, 111, 115, 
116, 117, 118, 220, 220), c = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 
1, 4), d = c(2, 2, 12, 12, 15, 12, 12, 2, 12, 12, 12, 14), e = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), f = c(20, 30, 25, 35, 45, 55, 
60, 65, 70, 75, 75, 80), h = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1A", "2A", "3A", "4A", 
"5A", "7A", "9A"), class = "factor"), i = c(12, 16, 17, 19, 20, 
15, 18, 17, 17, 13, 14, 15)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
"e", "f", "h", "i"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

set.seed(5)
m$rand <- runif(nrow(m))

m[a==113,"i"] <- c(10,11,12)[1+findInterval(unlist(m[m$a==113,"rand",with=F]),c(0.25,0.50))]
```

Is there any easy way to draw from a values vector which has all these correspondences in one place. For instance have [for a==113 c(0.25,0.50),values=c(10,11,12)] [for a==111 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)] [for a==115 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)] all in one table or frame and draw from these whenever the findinterval function is used? The i column is supposed to be replaced by values wherever related. What I want to do is to read the values (e.g. c(10,11,12)) from another file and put in the findinterval function whenever needed.

Comment: Why are you bothering to use data.table if you are ignoring most of  the data.table syntax and memory efficiency? What are your desired numbers?

Comment: It gave me error without using the data.table. The desired numbers are 10 and 11 (for rand less than 0.45 get number 10 AND for rand greater than 0.45 get number 11). I will use the same process for other parts of the table.

Comment: WHere are you pulling these numbers from?

Comment: These are some previously set numbers. I do not know how to set them before to read in from. These are some examples: [for a==112 c(0.25,0.50),values=10,11,12]    [for a==114 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=(1,2,3,4)]

Comment: Please post a reproducible example of what you want (edit your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 0 and 1 are what is being returned by `findInterval`. That result should be used to index the values you are interested in. Try:

```
> k[a==113,"WWW"] <- c(10,11)[1+findInterval(unlist(k[k$a==113,"rand",with=F]),c(0.45))]
 # or draw from the values vector based on your comment 
# (which should instead be an edit rather than a comment.
values=c(10,11,12)
k[a==113,"WWW"] <- values[1+findInterval(unlist(k[k$a==113,"rand",with=F]),c(0.45))]
> k
     a b  c d  e WWW      rand
1: 113 2  2 1 20  10 0.2002145
2: 113 2  2 1 30  11 0.6852186
3: 112 1 12 1 25  17 0.9168758
4: 114 1 12 1 35  19 0.2843995
```

Since vectors are 1 based rather than zero based you need to add the 1 to the result.

Comment: Thanks DWin. This solved my problem. Is there any easy way to draw from a values vector which has all these correspondences in one place. For instance have [for a==112 c(0.25,0.50),values=c(10,11,12)] [for a==114 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)]a==114 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)] all in one table or frame and draw from these whenever the findinterval function is used?

Comment: Post the output of dput() from that dataframe and we might have better chance of actually figuring out what you actually are working with.

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question window. Thanks!

Comment: I think there would be a solution to what I imagine the problem to be, and it would involve first using the split function. My problem at the moment is that none of your columns look like the breaks you have been asking for and I cannot figure out what problem you now want to solve. (Perhaps adding the random column and changing column "i" to "WWW"? But which column is supposed to be "values"? Would that be "f"?)  Too many loose-ends for me. My suggestion would be to compose a new question and post using the dput output.

Comment: Thanks DWin. I edited the question again. Now, it has the dput output and the data.

Comment: The "i" column is to be replaced by ... what? From values in which column? The phrase "whatever related" is has no meaning to me.

Comment: By values I meant those set up separated from the m data frame. Those are [for a==113 c(0.25,0.50),values=c(10,11,12)] [for a==111 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)] [for a==115 c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)] as mentioned before. The values to be replaced to "i" column are not in the table and are outside the data.frame. They are some constant numbers based on the probability intervals mentioned for each number in the "a" column.

Comment: So you apparently need to assemble these in a list (since there are unequal numbers of breaks, and will need to use lapply across the entries in the list. `spl.list <- list('113' = list(breaks=c(0.25,0.50),values=c(10,11,12) ), '111' =list( breaks=c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)) , '115' =list( breaks= c(0.25,0.50,0.75),values=c(1,2,3,4)) )`